# Azure load balancer Method

Tags: wcf, azure, load

I was interested in creating a new load balancer for my WCF Service which is deployed on my Azure Account. While creating it, I saw "Load Balancing Methods". I let the default one which is called "Performance". May I have some information on which one should I choose, what are the purposes of those Methods?

Here's a screenshot which can describe better what I'm actually interested in.[image]

Comment: Not sure which load-balancer feature you're talking about (it would help to edit your question to include that, maybe a screenshot?). And until you to edit your question provide more information about your app and why you need a load balancer, it's fairly impossible to help you choose.

Comment: My question sir is about which one should I choose, because I dont know whats the purpose of each one of them. I need it for my WCF application, which returns objects, and gets requests from multiple active sites with millions of users.

Comment: Ah - you're referring to Traffic Manager. This type of question belongs on ServerFault. But... before posting one, you should first read the basics of the traffic manager service, as it's well-documented: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/ - note: It's not the same as a load-balancer.

Comment: Ok, thank you and have a good day.